# Is there a way to keep a timer going when phone is locked?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to recreate the Stopwatch functionality of Android's default 'Clock' app, but cannot seem to find a way to keep the timer going when the screen locks.

It doesn't stop immediately but the time it continues for seems to vary and definitely does stop - I tested with both the Android 'Clock' app and mine running at the same time.

Any way around this? I was looking into Isolates, but after implementing it I don't think that is the solution here. I've been searching and I guess what I need is to be able to run Background Tasks?

Can we do this in dart+flutter? If not any suggestions? I assume you would be able to (or have to) do it natively in the android/ios codebase.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem I faced when I was building a music Player application. The [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package helped me with this background tasking. You might just go through this package code and implement as per your timer application and it will surely do fine.